# Proper way of adding a glossary to an article

Tags: article-writing

I am thinking of adding a glossary to an article of mine, I was wondering if there is an etiquette regarding adding a glossary of symbols and notations? To be frank I have not seen one in any recent articles and I do not remember any specific old paper with a glossary.

Comment: I have never seen glossaries in mathematical papers, and rarely in books.

Comment: But I think it will really help the reader to identify all the symbols and notations fast.